# Sanitize everything to text with htmlpurifier

Tags: php, xss, sanitization, htmlpurifier

Im pretty new to xss protection and this got me thinking if its safe.

If I use eg:

```
$lol = "javascript:alert('asd')";

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', '');
$cleaned = $purifier->purify($lol);


<a href="<?php echo $cleaned; ?>"><?php echo $cleaned; ?></a>
```

The code above will still output a alert function, eg if I press on the a link a pop-up will show.

Is that safe considering XSS?

Also im using `$config->set('HTML.Allowed', '');` since I ONLY want to output text and none HTML whatsoever.

Should I then add a regex to check for `;:` eg `[^:;]` just to be on the safe side.

Worth pointing out is that all data that users submit to my site will only be outputted between `<p>` tags and `<h1>` tags.

Thanks in advance,

// XSS newbie.

Comment: Sidenote: The reason HTML Purifier isn't catching that is because it's not HTML - it's data in an HTML attribute. If you were to put `<a href="javascript:alert('asd')">javascript:alert('asd')</a>` into HTML Purifier, it would do what you want - because at that point, it knows that it has to treat `javascript:alert('asd')` as a link. But like Pez said, it's probably overkill for what you want to achieve. :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't overcomplicate your sanitization, just do `$cleaned = htmlentities($lol);` this will convert all possible html tags into their appropriate html entity as a string.

You say `my site will only be outputted between <p> tags and <h1> tags` so in this case an htmlentities will surfice as the user will not be able to use html, so they could not create a link.

However in this **test case**, as you are echoing the `$cleaned` string into an a href even after removing the html tags (e.g. there are NO html tags in `$lol`) valid javascript is still output.

XSS usually relies on script tags e.g. `<script>alert('asd');</script>` in this case there are none.

If you would still like to be able to echo into an ahref, may I suggest stripping the word javascript: from the front? Or perhaps converting all non-alpha numeric characters into html entities.

Comment: Thanks, but since im only outputting the data inside hardcoded <p> and <h1> tags, can I just simply use strip_tags when im inserting the data to the database, then use htmlspecialchars($the_data); when im outputting it? I just want to make sure no xss can pass it, - and im using bind_param to protect against sql-inject

Comment: @user2722667 `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($input))` should do what you want and is safe, yeah. :) (Don't forget the other two parameters of `htmlspecialchars()`, though; encoding is especially important.)